# 3rd party tool that can generate a list related articles for a japanese-language site

Tags: javascript, ajax, unicode, internationalization, related-content

I run a site with a large number of news articles. I'm looking for a 3rd party tool(or widget) that, when placed on an article page, would generate a list of related articles within the same site.

So my requirements are:

- Returns a list of links to related articles
- Has to be integrated front-end (javascript,ajax,etc)
- Has to sustain large traffic and display results quickly
- Most importantly, **must support Japanese language content**

Any ideas on tools, widgets, services out there would be great - thanks!

Comment: What are your criteria for two articles being related?

Comment: @deceze - The criteria would be that the overall theme or subject of the article is matched. I understand this can be done using various methods; for example counting what keyword gets repeated the most in a given article body - then associating it with other articles that have the same common keyword.

Comment: Sounds like you want a keyword extractor for Japanese text (ie. the webpage content). Japanese keyword extraction might be a bit black magicy for non-native developers as Japanese doesn't have whitespace!

Answer (score 0):

nRelate has this exact product as a simple WordPress plugin - used both for related content and for most popular content.

http://nrelate.com/install-products/

Gravity also does something similar, but I believe you have to be a large website to gain access to their tools.

http://www.gravity.com/publishers